# Best way to include helper class in sub-controller : require_once or JLoader

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, controller

I have created a helper file `test.php` as following:

**administrator/components/com_compname/helpers/test.php**

```
class TestHelper{
   //class methods
}
```

In **controllers/subcontrollername.php**
We can use either of them:

1) `require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'helpers'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'test.php' );`

2) `JLoader::register('TestHelper','/path/to/test.php');`

But I am wondering which of the two is appropriate and why or does this even matter or not. Can anyone please guide me on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually `JLoader::register('TestHelper','/path/to/test.php');` dosen't load file, it just registers it to be able to autoload file if class is instantiated.

**Do require it instantly, you want to use:**

```
JLoader::import('TestHelper','/path/to/test.php');
```

Note: for this your file name should be `TestHelper.php`.

which will

1. `include_once` the file if it exists (with `require_once` you would get PHP error, if it dosen't exist. Now you would get pretty Joomla! error).
2. Will remember that this file is already loaded and wont `include_once` it again. This results in minor performance gain.

which won't

1. `JLoader::register()` your class, so you can't use `JLoader::load()` later.

**All in all:**

1. Minor performance gain.
2. It's good practice to follow coding style of framework (though Joomla! dosen't do it everywhere itself).
3. You can use dot notation for class name (not applicable for `*Helper` classes.).

**Dot notation example**

`jimport('sub.path.classname','/path/to/')`

would `include_once` file in `/path/to/sub/path/classname.php`

**NOTE**

`JLoader::import('TestHelper','/path/to/test.php')`

has shorthand

`jimport('TestHelper','/path/to/test.php')`

Comment: Thank you for a very nice explanation. But I would need your help a little further. I used `JLoader::import('TestHelper','/path/to/test.php');` but it gives me an error 'TestHelper class not found' . I did the following after importing the helper file: `TestHelper::getTestfunction()` . But it does not work

Comment: Is your `/path/to` without `.php`? Path has to be absolute. So in your case `JLoader::import('TestHelper', JPATH_COMPONENT.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'helpers');`

Comment: no it was with php. `JLoader::import('TestHelper',JPATH_COMPONENT.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'helpers'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'test.php');` But I also tried without `.php`. Still it doen't work

Comment: You file should be named `TestHelper.php`.

Comment: perfect! it worked :) I thought the 1st parameter is the `classname` . But realized now it must be `filename`. Thank you Rene

Comment: Just to add to this, `JLoader::register()` actually registers the class to the autoloader using a given path.  So later when you want to use the class you don't need a second import statement of any kind, PHP will load it automagically through the autoloading mechanisms of JLoader after that initial call to the register method.